# Será que esta certo? A pergunta e a duvida esta no comentario do codigo

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Curso Java Script</title>


/* Exercicio: Seguindo o resultado do exercício anterior adicione um input em tela e um botão como a seguir:
<input type="text" name="nome">
<button onClick="adicionar()">Adicionar</button>
Ao clicar no botão, a função adicionar() deve ser disparada adicionando um novo item a lista de
nomes baseado no nome preenchido no input e renderizando o novo item em tela juntos aos
demais itens anteriores. Além disso, o conteúdo do input deve ser apagado após o clique.


ACHO QUE ESTA FALTANDO A PARTE DE QUANDO CLICA NO BOTÃO PARA ADICIONAR NOME FICAR UM DEBAIXO DO OUTRO NA PAGINA, POIS O CONSOLE LOG DO CÓDIGO USEI SÓ PARA TESTE PARA VER SE ESTAVA CADASTRANDO CERTO, MAIS NÃO SEI SE ERA ISSO MESMO QUE ERA PARA FAZER.
*/


</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <input type="text" id = "name" name="nome" onclick = "this.value = ''"/>
        <button class='li' id = 'li' onclick="adicionar()">Adicionar</button>
        <span id="texto"></span>
    </div>
    <script>
    var btnElement = document.querySelector('li');

    function adicionar(){

        var nome = document.getElementById('name').value;

        document.getElementById('texto').innerHTML = nome;
        console.log(nome);
        nome ='';
        document.getElementById('name').value = "";
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Poderia dar mais detalhes do que está tentando fazer.

Comment: Seguindo o resultado do exercício anterior adicione um input em tela e um botão como a seguir:
<input type="text" name="nome">
<button onClick="adicionar()">Adicionar</button>
Ao clicar no botão, a função adicionar() deve ser disparada adicionando um novo item a lista de
nomes baseado no nome preenchido no input e renderizando o novo item em tela juntos aos
demais itens anteriores. Além disso, o conteúdo do input deve ser apagado após o clique.

Comment: Só esta faltando a parte de deixar os nomes um embaixo do outro no HTML

Comment: O console.log ali só usei de help para ver se estava cadastrando certo, mas vou excluir ele, depois de tudo.

Comment: Ele esta apagando da pagina HTML.

Comment: "Seguindo o resultado do exercício anterior"? Que exercício anterior? É relevante conhecer esse execício? Quanto ao continuação da explicação, o procedimento do site é editar a pergunta e colocar essas informações na própria pergunta pois as respostas apresentadas são dadas de acordo ao conteúdo da pergunta.

Comment: A partir do seguinte vetor:
var nomes = ["Diego", "Gabriel", "Lucas"];
Preencha uma lista (<ul>) no HTML com os itens da seguinte forma:
● Diego
● Gabriel
● Lucas

Comment: Coloca na pergunta para poder lhe dar uma resposta.

Comment: Toda vez que clickar no botão ja com o nome digitado, colocar o nome seguinte aabixo na pagina ele apaga esta aparecendo só no console, ou será que seria isso? Mais acho que não.

Comment: A pergunta é essa decima mais vou colar aqui tambm: A partir do seguinte vetor:
var nomes = ["Diego", "Gabriel", "Lucas"];
Preencha uma lista (<ul>) no HTML com os itens da seguinte forma:
● Diego
● Gabriel
● Lucas

Comment: Reiterando: **Edite** a sua pergunta pressionando o botão [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/450500/edit) localizado logo abaixo da sua pergunta. Eu não vou apresentar uma resposta baseado nas informações dos comentários. Os comentários servem apenas para esclarecer detalhes. A norma do site é que o escopo das respostas devam se deter ao conteúdo apresentado nas perguntas e não dos comentários.

Comment: Não vou te dar a solução do exercício por questão prática, ele foi criado para você aprender JavaScript, no seu código, quando você digita e clica no botão, ele troca o conteúdo de dentro do <SPAN>, para funcionar corretamente, antes de escrever o nome no innerHtml do SPAN, você tem que pegar o valor dele, e concatenar com "<br>"+nome essa é a lógica, agora é só codar....

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que seja essa a solução que você procura. Coloquei com log para melhor compreensão. Se for todo o texto para aparecer na tela é só inciar a variavel **i** do **for** com 0 (**i=0**)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="app">

    <input type="text" id = "name" name="nome" oninput="adicionar()"/>
    <button class='li' id = 'li' onclick="adicionar()">Adicionar</button>
    <span id="texto"></span>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var btnElement = document.querySelector('li'); 
 function adicionar(){ 
  var nome = document.getElementById('name').value; 
  var nomeP = nome.split(" ");
  console.log(nomeP);
  var palavra = "";

  if (nomeP.length>1) {
   for(var i=1;i<nomeP.length;i++)
    palavra =  palavra.concat(nomeP[i]+' ');
  }
  document.getElementById('texto').innerHTML = palavra;

  console.log(nome); nome =''; 
  //document.getElementById('name').value = ""; 
 }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Boa noite bernardo tudo bem? Então não é bem isso, eu queria que cada nome que eu fosse adicionando fosse aparecendo um debaixo do outro na pagina do HTM, só isso que falta para eu conseguir terminar o exercicio, o console.log ali só deixei para eu ver se estava armazenando tudo ok mas vou tirar ele depois. Vou mandar a pergunta do exercicio abaixo. Mas valeu desde já, abraços.

Comment: Seguindo o resultado do exercício anterior adicione um input em tela e um botão como a seguir:
<input type="text" name="nome">
<button onClick="adicionar()">Adicionar</button>
Ao clicar no botão, a função adicionar() deve ser disparada adicionando um novo item a lista de
nomes baseado no nome preenchido no input e renderizando o novo item em tela juntos aos
demais itens anteriores. Além disso, o conteúdo do input deve ser apagado após o clique.